# A* Pathfinding with 2x2 player or larger

Tags: path-finding

I am very familiar with A* and is able to make it work well. However I am looking for resources describing how to do find a path with a player size of 2x2 instead of the usual 1x1 on a 2d map. So for example, if there is a choke point where only 1x1 can fit through, the 2x2 player must find another path around.

I have googled but with no results. I am not sure what this problem is called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to find what I was looking for, sorry. If you are looking for a similar solution to pathfinding with different unit sizes, check out:
https://harablog.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/clearance-based-pathfinding/

Comment: I've linked this question to several existing Q&A threads we have about this topic. Please be sure to search for previous answers before posting a new question.